# update all the fields at once in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where i wanted to apply url field of a table in DB. For eg.. all the URL's are of format

```
  ~/production/Class_ext/MgrLoginChoices.asp?menu1=Instruct
```

Now I need to change them to the format

```
 ~/Secure/production/Class_ext/MgrLoginChoices.asp?menu1=Instruct
```

I just need to add a Secure folder before everything. I dont want to do it manually. Is there a way i can update with the query.. Please help me out.. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

one way

```
update Table
SET URL = replace(URL,'~','~/Secure')
WHERE URL LIKE '~%'
```

Remember that will change all the ~, if you have more than 1 ~ in the column, then use the method below which uses STUFF

you can also use **STUFF**

```
update Table
SET URL = STUFF(URL,3,0,'Secure/')
WHERE URL LIKE '~%'
```

example that you can run

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @v = '~/production/Class_ext/MgrLoginChoices.asp?menu1=Instruct'

SELECT @v, STUFF(@v,3,0,'Secure/')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update urls
set url = '~/secure' + right(url, len(url) -1);
```